# Can a Windows Store App find out if developer mode is activated on the device?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-10, win-universal-app

Is there some API in Windows 10 to find out if [developer mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn706236.aspx) is activated?
I guess the answer is probably no. But maybe there is a special trick?

Reading the registry key will not work, because Store Apps are not allowed to access the registry.

The use case is: show some additional menu entry which is useful only for debugging.

Comment: This would be very useful if possible. Currently I am enabling this kind of "developer menu" with a special tap/click combination on a specific app page.

Comment: The closes API I found is Package.IsDevelopmentMode, which indicates whether the package was installed in development. But there's no such for indicating if the app is running is development mode.

Comment: @Jackie: Thanks, this seem to be exactly what I need for my use case. If you add this as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there some API in Windows 10 to find out if developer mode is activated?

There's no API available yet for UWP app to find if Developer mode is activated.

However, you can try using

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.IsDevelopmentMode
```

It indicates whether the package is installed in development mode.

For more details, see to  https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn175745.